# How can i send a message to whatsapp group?

Tags: twilio, message, whatsapp, send

I need to send a message to WhatsApp group, Is it possible with Twilio? Thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

No I don't think they do
one of the faq [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/best-practices-and-faqs#api)

```
Can I send messages to WhatsApp groups or manage groups?

WhatsApp deprecated the Groups API in April 2020. Twilio offers a group messaging solution using the Conversations API. You may reference this sample code in CodeExchange: WhatsApp Group Messaging. For more info, please refer to Twilio Conversations.
```

But with Twilio's [Conversations API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/using-whatsapp-conversations), you can implement group chats in WhatsApp, a feature that is not offered natively in WhatsApp's API.

Comment: How is this possible if there is no underlying WhatsApp API to call? What do the messages sent through Twilio's API look like in WhatsApp?